# How can I create 2 SVGs and use jquery.extend() to combine them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have two methods that return SVG objects. The first returns SVG and the second returns an SVG rectangle. In the second method I want to use `jquery.extend(true,...,..)` to combine the objects. I want the return object to be the rectangle SVG (from the second method). The reason I didn't create a shape in the first method was because I just need the attributes. I use the shape from the second method (rectangle).

Method 1:

```
RedlineElement.prototype.exportSVG = function() {
    var svg = document.createElement('SVG');

    svg.setAttribute("stroke-opacity",  this.getOpacity());
    svg.setAttribute("stroke",this.getStrokeColor());
    svg.setAttribute('stroke-width', this.getStrokeWidth());
    svg.setAttribute("x", this.getOriginX());
    svg.setAttribute("y", this.getOriginY());

    return svg;
};


RedlineElementRectangle.prototype.exportSVG = function() {
        var svgRect = "`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`";
        var rect = document.createElementNS(svgRect, 'rect');
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', this.getHeight());
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', this.getWidth());
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fillColor', this.getFillColor());

        //custom SVG attributes
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'version', 1);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'elementType', sap.ui.vk.Redline.ElementType.Rectangle)

    return jQuery.extend(true, RedlineElement.prototype.exportSVG, rect);

};
```

but this keeps returning a non SVG rectangle element with random stuff.

[image: Console Image here]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already done so, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask good answerable questions.

Comment: @CJDennis Thnaks. I already have :)